# Detect and control on clientside when a kafkajs consumer or producer timeouts

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, kafkajs

Im new to kafka and to kafkajs.

I have made a Kafka producer and consumer using [kafkaJS](https://kafka.js.org/).

I want to know how can I control what happens on my js code when the consumer or producer times out on the connection with the kafka server.

I imagine there must be some sort of function assignment on the configuration, but I couldn't find anything on the docs so far.

Comment: Check the `await` operator used with `producer.connect()` and `consumer.connect()`, assign the result to a variable. See https://kafka.js.org/docs/producing and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, yet i have my structure well defined, controlling the async calls with awaits.

The value that the `connect()` function returns are not of use to me, since kafkaJS consumers and producers tries to reconnect after a timeout, and I do not wish for the process to end, I want it to retry the connection and have some custom code executed when a timeout is detected, for example, notify the user via an alert, so even if the `connect()` function returns something since I do not wish for the end its process, the return value is not of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for REQUEST_TIMEOUT event of [instrumentation events](https://kafka.js.org/docs/instrumentation-events) of KafkaJS